# What Dojos Teach 'Police' Kendo?

Tags: judo, kendo, kenjutsu

The Japanese police have their own version of kendo that incorporates Judo moves.

Is there any other place, other than the Japanese police academies that teaches a similar version of kendo or a similar competition style with another name?

(just think this style looks cool and would like to learn if I ever travel to Japan)

Comment: Interesting question, but the sources I see (on a quick google skim) say that the police kendo curriculum is aggressive, but does not necessarily incorporate judo — rather that the choice is to train kendo *or* judo. Could you point to where you saw this "kendo with judo moves"?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/emptymindfilms/posts/2560513027350077
It looks like the Haga Dojo of the Budokan has a class...  I assume this is basically the same as the police rules.

Comment: From what I gather, kendo used to include throws and sweeps. As the sport progressed, they banned throws, body checks, and foot sweeps. But some schools of kendo still allow these kinds of things. The police kendo variation you're talking about allows body checks, sweeps, and sword cut to a downed player. I believe you don't get any points for a foot sweep, but you do get a point if you can get a sword strike while your opponent is down. I don't know much else.